# What would be the best approach to integrate with different vendors APIs?

Tags: api, rest, connection, integration

We are building an application where we have to integrate with a bunch(100-200s) of different vendor APIs. These vendors accept payload in XML or JSON format. Also, payload structure can be different for each vendor. We are storing data in generic JSON format in our database, and have to convert it to vendor specific format before making API call. What should be the approach to solve this? Currently, we are planning to keep a mapping in database, which converts our generic format to vendor specific format.

We have tried using PIRI for JSON remapping -- https://piri.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

We would like to know your thoughts to solve this problem. Also, are there any third party tools that we can use here?

Comment: Piri will create for you a centralized place where you capture all the mappings with your clients, it doesn't matter if you persist the data on your database, at the end of the day you will need to map each client to make a specific API call

Comment: Yes, we are persisting data for auditing purposes. PIRI does not require us to store data in database.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that if every client has it's own specific contract you don't have another way to end with a custom call for each one of them

Comment: What I was trying to say is that if every client has it's own specific contract you don't have another way to end with a custom call for each one of them

Comment: Yes, agree with your point of making custom call. We are planning to write a transformation layer that converts data from our generic format to vendor format.

Comment: You can implement and abstract factory pattern there. Where you have a transformation layer and each client has its own transformation method.https://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern